# Pulling a single record from Android SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im creating this database for a converter. Its like an 2 dimensional array. If i'm not mistaking i should look something like the picture(not in same order as in the code).

Now `"getData(String x, String y)"` method should go to x row of the data base return the value in y column. E.g. according to the PICTURE if I call `"getData("CAD", "EUR")"`, the method should return `"0.64955"`.

But the app crushes.
LogCat:

```
07-23 06:15:10.925: E/AndroidRuntime(28756): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-23 06:15:10.925: E/AndroidRuntime(28756): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, AUD, CAD, EUR, GBP, USD FROM table





public class database {

        private Db DbHelper;
        private Context ct;
        private SQLiteDatabase database;

        private static class Db extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

            public Db(Context context) {
                super(context, "db", null, 1);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String query; 

                query = "CREATE TABLE table (null, AUD, CAD, EUR, GBP, USD)"; 
                db.execSQL(query);
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO AUD VALUES (AUD, 1, 1.00074, 0.65018, 0.54310, 0.90261)");
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO CAD VALUES (CAD, 0.99888, 1, 0.64955, 0.54259, 0.90177)");
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO EUR VALUES (EUR, 1.53774, 1.53910, 1, 0.83528, 1.38818)");
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO GBP VALUES (GBP, 1.84069, 1.84240, 1.19697, 1, 1.66174)");
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO USD VALUES (USD, 1.10769, 1.10872, 0.72030, 0.60170, 1)");
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }}
        public  database(Context c){
            ct = c;
        }


        public database open(){
            DbHelper = new Db(ct);
            database = DbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public void close(){
            DbHelper.close();
        }


        public double getData(String x, String y) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
String [] col = new String[]{"id", "AUD", "CAD", "EUR", "GBP", "USD"};
    Cursor c = database.query("table", col, null, null, null, null, null);
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(y);
    String result = "";
    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        result = c.getString(iRow);
    }
    return result;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])

Comment: When you don't know anything about SQL, read some SQL tutorial first, and try out your commands in the `sqlite3` command-line shell or in some tool like SQLite Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You created a table named "table", but the string "table" is an [SQL keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html); try changing it:

```
query = "CREATE TABLE my_table (null, AUD, CAD, EUR, GBP, USD)";
```

Comment: `null` is a keyword, too.

Answer (score 0):

issues in your code.

1. "table" string used as tablename is a keyword. So use different name. e.g. currency_tab
2. As well as you cannot give column name as "null". So we e.g. currency_name
3. Also you need to specify datatype and constraint if any for each column.
4. In select query you are using one column name id, but you are not adding it the table creation. Also as per your insertion query you are not supplying any value for id field so need to make id field as Autoincrement.

so doing all the changes, your query should look something like:

```
query = "CREATE TABLE currency_tab (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, currency_name TEXT NOT NULL, AUD TEXT NOT NULL, CAD TEXT NOT NULL, EUR TEXT NOT NULL, GBP TEXT NOT NULL, USD TEXT NOT NULL)";
```

Comment: SQLite does not require data types. The `id` column is useless when you're using `currency_name` as PK. You overlooked all the erros in the INSERT statements.

Comment: it has to be added as questioner is referring in the select query. this is the select query "SELECT id, AUD, CAD, EUR, GBP, USD FROM table"

Comment: It's the column that you called `currency_name`.

Comment: ok. let me modify my answer so it does not misguide any body. I would request if you can modify in the way it does not misguide anybody else looking at the post, then it would be really great. :)